# Slim3 - Container: Class not found

Tags: php, slim, psr-4

My source code **structure**:

- src

  - controllers

    - controller.php
    - Auth

      - AuthController.php
    - User

      - UserController.php
  - models

**composer.json**:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

**AuthController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\User;

use App\Controllers\Controller;


class AuthController extends Controller
{  
    ...
}
```

**UserController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\User;

use App\Models\User;

use App\Controllers\Controller;


class UserController extends Controller
{  
   ...
}
```

in Slim app:

```
$container = $app->getContainer();  

$container['AuthController'] = function ($container){
    return new App\Controllers\Auth\AuthController($container);
};

$container['UserController'] = function ($container){
    return new App\Controllers\User\UserController($container);
};
```

I get an error when calling function from UserController:

**Class 'App\Controllers\User\UserController' not found**

And also IntelliJ marks the code and gives notification: Undefined class UserController.

Working with AuthController works fine.

In my opinion I got wrong namespacing, but I am not sure how to change it.

I have also run:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Controllers` as the namespace class. But in your directory structure `controller` is lower case. You have to capitalize `controllers` directory name to `Controllers`. Then your namespace can be usable.

Comment: I have changed the directory name to `Controllers` but it has no effect.

Comment: But After running compose dump-autoload it is working